# SSRS usw two matrix for one dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to build an SSRS (2017) report that would look like it's implementing two matrices.  I have one dataset with fields:

VendorName
Project
BillYear
Amount

I want to show one line per vender and pivot on both Project and BillYear so my report would look like

Vendor Project1 Project2 Project3 2017 2018 2019
-- with sum(amount) for the data.

Can this even be done?

Thank you in advance.

Matthew Wells
matthew.wells@firstbyte.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table with adjacent column groups to get the desired layout. An easy way to start off is by using the Table/Matrix wizard. This will help create the initial row and column groups for you. Of course you can do this without the wizard as well.

[image]

Next, add an adjacent column group to the right. This will be grouped by BillYear. The resulting table should look something like this:

[image]

Now you will get one row per vendor along with columns for each project and bill year. However many there happen to be. You can add rows/columns outside these groups to get subtotals as needed.

Comment: Thank you!  That was short, clear and concise.  Worked perfectly!